# How can I make a CSS variable that is defined using another variable reflect changes to the dependency?

Tags: css, css-variables

I'd like to use CSS variables to define some compound properties. In this example, I'm defining a `--border-width` variable as well as a `--border` variable that uses the `--border-width` variable. I then override the border width value on certain elements:

```css
:root {
  --border-width: 1px;
  --border: var(--border-width) solid #000;
}

.demo {
  border: var(--border);
  margin: 1em;
}

.demo.active {
  --border-width: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  Should have thin border
</div>

<div class="demo active">
  Should have thick border
</div>
```

I know that the new variable is being applied to the element; I can see it in the inspector and if I add an explicit `border-width: var(--border-width)` property to `.demo`, it applies the expected width value. However, it appears that `--border` hasn't been recalculated to reflect the change to `--border-width`.

I don't want each of my elements to have to specify all of the longhand properties each time I use something with a shorthand, but it seems like I'm missing something fundamental about CSS variables.

For example, I'd prefer to not have to do this:

```css
:root {
  --border-width: 1px;
  --border-style: solid;
  --border-color: #000;
}

.demo {
  border: var(--border-width) var(--border-style) var(--border-color);
  
  /*
  Or this
  
  border-width: var(--border-width);
  border-style: var(--border-style);
  border-color: var(--border-color);
  */
  
  margin: 1em;
}

.demo.active {
  --border-width: 10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  Should have thin border
</div>

<div class="demo active">
  Should have thick border
</div>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks! I knew had to have been asked before, but all of my searching wasn't pulling any duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that your `.demo` element has the `border` applied to it that you set in `:root`. However, in your `.demo.active` you merely *redefine* the CSS variable `--border-width` (as opposed to making use of the existing one). You need to explicitly use the property `border-width`.

In order to reuse the `--border-width` variable in `.demo.active`, you'd again be looking to make use of `var()` with `border-width: var(--border-width)`:

```css
:root {
  --border-width: 1px;
  --border: var(--border-width) solid #000;
}

.demo {
  border: var(--border);
  margin: 1em;
}

.demo.active {
  border-width: var(--border-width);
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  Should have thin border
</div>

<div class="demo active">
  Should have thick border
</div>
```

Note that this will copy what was set in the `:root` `--border-width`. *However*, given that you also mention that you're expecting a *thicker* border, what I suspect you may actually be looking for is to either override this setting (with `border-width: 10px`), or extend it to also include an addition, with 
`border-width: var(--border-width) + 10px`:

```css
:root {
  --border-width: 1px;
  --border: var(--border-width) solid #000;
}

.demo {
  border: var(--border);
  margin: 1em;
}

.demo.active {
  border-width: var(--border-width) + 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  Should have thin border
</div>

<div class="demo active">
  Should have thick border
</div>
```

Comment: *you merely redefine the CSS variable `--border-width`* — yes, my intention is that by doing so, the `--border` variable reflects the change, then `border: var(--border)` would as well. Effectively, I'm looking for a cascade of the variables.

Comment: In the OP, I stated *if I add an explicit `border-width: var(--border-width)` property*, but followed that up with *I don't want each of my elements to have to specify all of the longhand properties*; are you stating that what I want is impossible?

Comment: Essentially yes, I believe so -- something would still need to make *use* of that `-border-width` variable, with `var()`. If you're looking to apply a variable hierarchy in that regard, you're better off looking into a pre-processor like LESS, and nesting selectors (possibly making use of the parent selector `&`). I don't think that can be done in pure CSS, as the pre-processor simply compiles out each of the variables like above.

Comment: I don't follow your first example, as it doesn't have a think border in either case. Please also see my update where I show a way to make it work by only defining an updated variable.

Comment: imho the first example is missing `--border-width: 10px;`, but essentially, yes, you would have to redefine `--border` for it to take the new `--border-width` into account. That makes sense tho. If `.active` was capable of changing the :root `--border`, then both the active and non active elements would have a thick border. It's more a question of scope than "cascade".